# Getting user location in Android Studio app

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location, geocoding

I have an app (written in Android Studio) and I need to get a location from the user. The location can be either the current location or a different location that the user chooses on Google Maps. The problem is I can't find a way to let the user choose a location on Google Maps and save the location as parameters in my app (lattitude, longtitude). I would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

I searched the internet for solutions but didn't find anything that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for two different things. One thing is to get the current location using [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager). There are plenty of tutorials on the web so I won't explain this.

The second thing is to ask the user to pick a location on Google Maps. For this you (not the users of your app) need a Google account which you probably have. Visit https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started and click "Get Started". You have to create an API key. It's possibly not free.

[image]

When you have the API key you can start coding. A quick start guide for the **Maps SDK for Android** including an example can be found under https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start.